# Selecting only certain Shapes in a dynamic range

Tags: vba, coreldraw

In the code seen here:

```
Dim i As Long
Dim s, s2 As Shape
Dim sr As ShapeRange
Dim DupCounter As Integer

DupCounter = 1

Do Until DupCounter > QUANTITY
sHape1.Duplicate

ActivePage.Shapes.All.CreateSelection

Set sr = ActiveSelectionRange

For i = 1 To sr.COUNT

    Set s = sr(i)

    If i = 1 Then
    s.SetPosition 0, 0

    ElseIf i <> 1 Then
    s.SetPosition s2.PositionX, (s2.PositionY + (s2.SizeHeight / 2) + 0.35 + (s.SizeHeight / 2))

    End If

    Set s2 = s
    Next i

    DupCounter = DupCounter + 1

    Loop
```

Shape1 comes from an import. The code does what I want it to do which is position each new shape that is duplicated based on the position of the shape that came in right before it. The problem as most of you can see is that it also repositions every shape on the page with each new import or duplicate. I need a way to just have the macro reposition the newly imported shape. Is there a way to have the code deselect all shapes except the new one and the on that was brought in right before it?

Answer (score 1):

I found a tutorial by GDG that shows the method to find shapes by searching for the static ID. You can watch it here -> http://community.coreldraw.com/talk/coreldraw_graphics_suite_x6/f/704/t/35486

John is amazing.